# How to copy a 2D numpy array into another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.eye(4,dtype=float)
b = np.zeros(1,dtype=[('model',float,(4,4)))])
```

how can I set the first element of `b` to have `a` as its model, ie how do I do this:

```
b[0]['model'] = a
```

(evidently, since I am asking the question, this does not work).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to simply switch it around:

```
b['model'][0] = a
```